# How can I pass variable in pthread_cond_signal function?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I am new to pthread programming. I am writing one sample code in which I want to transfer variable in pthread_cond_signal() as shown below

```
pthread_t th1,th2;
pthread_cond_t con1 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t con2 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void* fun(void *gh)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    flag=1;
    pthread_cond_wait(&con1,&mutex);
    printf("This is test\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

int main()
{
    char *s;
    int a;
    s=malloc(sizeof(char)*4);
    printf("Enter thread Number \n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    sprintf(s,"con%d",a);
    pthread_create(&th1,NULL,fun,NULL);
    sleep(1);
    while(flag==0) //wait until pthread_cond_wait is called  
    {}
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_signal((pthread_cond_t *)s);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_join(th1,NULL);
    pthread_join(th2,NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, your while(flag==0) loop may never end. You need a lock around every access to flag or the code may never read flag because it might be loaded into a register or it might be optimized out of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using threads. All threads of a program share memory with each other. The problem isn't reading variables from other threads. The problem is reading them in the correct order: not half-updated, out of date, or from the future.

Solving that problem is the entire reason for mutexes and semaphores and conditions.

What you want to do is NOT pass a value through pthread_cond_signal. What you do is set the value into some memory both threads can read and then send the signal.

I have to wonder why you considered that `pthread_cond_signal((pthread_cond_t *)s)` would work? `s` is not, and never was, a condition. A `pthread_cond_t` is not a value that you pass around. It is the structure that the POSIX Thread library uses to track condition states.